# Converting binary data to numeric format

Tags: type-conversion

I am working with a set of data in a binary data format (BLOB type within a SQLite db), and I need to convert it to numeric format.  The data is quite simple (just a list of decimal format numbers, once translated from binary). I  have an example of matched binary (hex) -> numeric data that I can work from (see below)

What is clear is that this is a 64 bit representation of a number, but when I try to directly convert it to what I think it is (a double), I don't get the right numbers.

Anyone have any ideas about what this format might be or how I might convert it?

```
00 00 00 80 9F 68 49 40     50.8174
00 00 00 80 45 EC 49 40     51.8459
00 00 00 60 6A FF 49 40     51.9954
00 00 00 60 2D B1 4A 40     53.3842
00 00 00 00 61 04 4B 40     54.0342
00 00 00 60 00 28 4B 40     54.3125
00 00 00 20 8C 31 4B 40     54.3871
```

Comment: If you find yourself tagging a question with 5 different languages then it's probably too broad.

Comment: Agreed, this question is not about Java, Python, C++, R, *OR* Sqlite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hex represents a double in little-endian format.
If you reverse the bytes and check against your first result you will see that it matches the decimal representation: http://binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?hexadecimal=4049689F80000000

Comment: Awesome!!  Thanks so much... I would have never thought to reverse the bytes.